# Rails controllers is not executed completely

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The same ajax code is executed from 2 different javascript functions. In both the function, the ajax calls a `connected` function in the controller to update a value in the `Room` table. But when the ajax is called from javascript function `connected`, the whole function gets executed, but not when it is called from `disconnected`.

## JavaScript functions in show.html.erb

```
var room_id = <%= @room.id %>
console.log("room id: ", room_id)

  session.on("connectionCreated", function(event) {
      console.log("connectionCreated");
       $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                data: JSON.stringify({ room: {connected: true}, _method:'put' }),
                url: "/rooms/" + room_id + "/connected",
                contentType: 'application/json'
              }).done(function( msg ){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       });
   });

  // Disconnect
  session.on('sessionDisconnected', function(event) {
    console.log("session Disconnected")
    $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            data: JSON.stringify({ room: {connected: false}, _method:'put' }),
            url: "/rooms/" + room_id + "/connected",
            contentType: 'application/json'
            }).done(function( msg ){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       });
    window.location.replace('<%= rooms_path %>');
  });
}
```

## Server.logs:

```
 From:
```

/Users/us186007/Desktop/WebApps/goldenyears/app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb @ line 38 RoomsController#connected:

```
36: def connected
37:     binding.pry
=> 38:     @room = Room.find params[:room_id]
39:     binding.pry
40:     @room.update_attributes(:connected => params[:room][:connected])
41: end

 [1] pry(#<RoomsController>)> continue
Room Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" = $1 
LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]

From: /Users/us186007/Desktop/WebApps/goldenyears/app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb @ line 40 RoomsController#connected:

36: def connected
37:     binding.pry
38:     @room = Room.find params[:room_id]
39:     binding.pry
=> 40:     @room.update_attributes(:connected => params[:room][:connected])
41: end
```

[1] pry(#)> continue
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
    No template found for RoomsController#connected, rendering head :no_content
    Completed 204 No Content in 20108ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)

```
  Started PUT "/rooms/6/connected" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-06 13:33:31 -0800
 Processing by RoomsController#connected as */*
Parameters: {"room"=>{"connected"=>false}, "room_id"=>"6"}
Started GET "/rooms" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-06 13:33:31 -0800

From: /Users/us186007/Desktop/WebApps/goldenyears/app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb @ line 38 RoomsController#connected:

36: def connected
37:     binding.pry
=> 38:     @room = Room.find params[:room_id]
39:     binding.pry
40:     @room.update_attributes(:connected => params[:room][:connected])
41: end
```

Even though server logs shows that it is hitting `connectedCreated` when it is called from `sessoinDisconected` function. 
How to understand what is going on? There are no error messages in server logs.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It is because of the line: `window.location.replace('<%= rooms_path %>');`. It redirects to rooms_path before it executes the controller code fully. I moved the redirect code to `done` part of `ajax`.